# UICollectionView scroll under TabBarItem

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, xcode7, storyboard-reference

I have a UITabbarController that points to a storyboard reference like the image below:

[image: UITabBarController pointing to storyboard reference]

In the storyboard I have a CollectionView and a TabBarItem:

[image: CollectionView and TabbarItem]

The problem is when I run this the CollectionView is under the tabbar item like

[image]

How do I make the CollectionView scroll respect the tabbaritem and not get under it?

Comment: You want the collectionview to go above the tab bar and hide it when scrolling?

Comment: I want the collectionview to stop on the tab bar so the it does not goes under it when I scroll.

Comment: have you tried setting "Clipsubviews" to true in the collectionview's superview? and maybe on the collecitonview itself?

Comment: Yes but it does't work.